# Is it possible to run vs 2019 code analyze by command and not by gui?

Tags: c#, analyzer

I'm using vs 2019 enterprise
Is it possible to run vs 2019 code analyze by command and not by gui?
if yes what command is it?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation the answer is YES and this is the command:

```
 vstest.console.exe ut.dll /Enablecodecoverage
```

`VSTest.Console.exe` is the command-line tool to run tests

`ut.dll` is the unit test project I want to run

`/Enablecodecoverage` is the option to run code coverage via cmd.

for more explanation on   vstest.console.exe see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Could you please explain what your command does? It would be helpful to understand what we are typing in our console / what exactly we are executing.

Comment: Sure, just added.

Answer (score 2):

yup, you can using the command /analyze

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/analyze-code-analysis?view=msvc-160

Comment: thank you. your link is very helpul